# vectorize a list of words by a vector of frequencies of the words

Tags: python

I'm trying to use naïve bayes to classify messages. Now, I have a list of strings `a` which are some words that I choose to be significative in helping calssifying messages. Now, given another list of strings `b` representing the set of words in a messsage, I want to vectorize `b` by counting the frequencies of each string in a. What I mean is for example `a=["qqq","www","eee","rrr","ttt"]` and `b=["aaa","sss","ddd","qqq","ttt"]` then the method should return `[1,0,0,0,1]` for vector b. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `vectorize`.  You mention 2 lists of strings.  `b` is a list.  Python doesn't have `vectors`.  List comprehensions are a common tool for iterating through lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
>>> a=["qqq","www","eee","rrr","ttt"]
>>> b=["aaa","sss","ddd","qqq","ttt"]

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(b)
>>> [c[i] for i in a]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

One potentially inefficient way of doing this is:

```
[b.count(x) for x in a]
```